# how to convert string value in a html check box to boolean?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-2, checkbox

i have checkbox group where it has three different values. stored and not stored is a boolean value and the "waiting" is string value . i am  passing a string value into the check bok. i have a error that says cannot convert bool to string...

Status

```
            <div class="field forCheckbox">
                <%:Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Stored)%>
                <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.Stored)%>
            </div>



            <div class="field forCheckbox">
                <%:Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Not Stored)%>
                <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.Not Stored)%>
            </div>


            <div class="field forCheckbox">
                <%:Html.CheckBoxFor(Convert.boolean(model=>model.Waiting))%>
                <%:Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Waiting) %>
            </div>
```

how do i do?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with balexandre's answer, but I think it's better to use 'Equals' in case of null value.
And it's useless to write 'cond?true:false'. 'cond' works.

```
<div class="field forCheckbox">
   <%:Html.CheckBox(model => {return "Waiting".Equals(model.Waiting)})%>
   <%:Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Waiting) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<%:Html.CheckBox("Waiting", Model.Waiting.ToLower() == "waiting"))%>
```

or Add to your Model a `boolean` property:

```
public bool WaitingBool { 
    get {
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Waiting) && 
           this.Waiting.ToLower() == "waiting") 
            return true;
        return false;
    } 
}
```

and you can use:

```
<%:Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.WaitingBool)%>
```

Comment: There is never a reason to write `? true : false`

Comment: @Slaks: Curious, why is that?